# Power series - radius of convergence in terms of other series

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Given series $S = \sum a_n x^n$ which has a finite radius $R_1$, how to compute radius $R_2$ for series $Q = \sum C^n a_n x^{n^2}$, where $C$ is any real constant.

My reasoning is it should be $1$ since $R_2 = \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} (C^n a_n)^{\frac{1}{n^2}} = 1 \cdot \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\frac{1}{R_1})^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$. This comes from $R_2$ being a radius of series $\sum b_k x^k$, where $b_k$ equals $C^{\sqrt{k}}a_{\sqrt{k}}$ for $k$ being a square of a natural number, and $0$ otherwise.
However that would mean $R_2$ equals $1$ Regardless of $R_1$ which seems counter intuitive.

Comment: As long as $R_1\neq0$, the radius of convergence of $Q$ at most $1$.